# How can I get link of a folder inside google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, drive

How can I get the id of the newly created folder.
when I run this code on google Colaboratory it just gives me the name of that folder.. not that id..
If you know how to get the link of that folder please let me know... [NB: I set all the folders as public]

I tried this code.. but it just gives me the name of that folder not the id..

```
from google.colab import drive
import os


# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Envato Share/')

# Create a new folder with the specified name
folder_name = input("Enter the folder name: ")

if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
    os.makedirs(folder_name)
else:
    print("Folder already exists.")

os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Envato Share/'+folder_name)
folder_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Envato Share/'+folder_name
folder_id = !echo $(basename "$folder_path")
print(folder_id)
#folder id looks like = 0BwHNmjAnD2r5flFLRklyZ0QzQkgzbVFpbjFyMzVsM3NBQXpoTnVydXZuRllRWHRncGJVRFk
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok one workaround I can think of is if you can give the current folder id in which you are creating new folder, then you can list all the items in current folder, that list will also have newly created folder using this function,

```
def currentDirectoryLister(folder_id):
    query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents"
    response = service.files().list(q=query, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True, corpora='allDrives').execute()
    itemsList = response.get('files')
    nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')
    while nextPageToken:
        response = service.files().list(q=query, pageToken=nextPageToken, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True, corpora='allDrives').execute()
        itemsList.extend(response.get('files'))
        nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')
    return itemsList
```

now you you have a list of all the items, you just have to check if it's a folder, then get it's id using :

```
 itemsList = currentDirectoryLister(id)
        for current in itemsList:
            if current['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                folder_id = current['id']
```

hope it helps